# AWS Elastic Beanstalk default CloudWatch log location for Java applications

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have deployed a JAR file in an AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment, using a load balancer and maximum 2 EC2 instances.

My environment seems to be using *the new unified CloudWatch agent*, not the legacy CloudWatch Logs Agent

In the environment configuration in the console I turned on "Instance log streaming to CloudWatch Logs", and now in CloudWatch Logs I get the following groups:

- `/aws/elasticbeanstalk/myapp-myenv/var/log/eb-engine.log`
- `/aws/elasticbeanstalk/myapp-myenv/var/log/eb-hooks.log`
- `/aws/elasticbeanstalk/myapp-myenv/var/log/nginx/access.log`
- `/aws/elasticbeanstalk/myapp-myenv/var/log/nginx/error.log`
- `/aws/elasticbeanstalk/myapp-myenv/var/log/web.stdout.log`

This is nice. Notably the web server accesses are in `access.log`, and even the STDOUT console output of my JAR file is in `web.stdout.log`. So far so good.

Now let's say I want my JAR application to generate a log file and have it picked up automatically in CloudWatch Logs. I've read the [Elastic Beanstalk EC2 logging documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html) which says that I can bundle special `.ebextensions` in my application to indicate new logging locations "[i]f your application generates logs in a location that isn't part of the default configuration for your environment's platform".

In the short term I'd rather not create an `.ebextensions` file. The part about "… a location … part of the default configuration …" intrigues me.

**Is there a default location for the Elastic Beanstalk Java platform logs?** In other words, is there some default location such as `/var/log/app/` that I can simply have my application log to (e.g. via environment variable configuration) and have CloudWatch Logs with the new unified agent automatically pick them up, without needing to create an `.ebextensions` file? (As a second best solution, is there a way I can configure the location using the AWS console?)

Answer (score 5):

It is very easy to configure this in the new unified CloudWatch agent. The agent picks up any configuration files present in the directory - `/etc/amazon/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/`

You can create a custom config file in that directory,

```
{
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
                "collect_list": [
                    {
                        "file_path": "path_to_file/app1.log",
                        "log_group_name": "/app/app.log",
                        "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can have [multiple config files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-common-scenarios.html#CloudWatch-Agent-multiple-config-files) like this. These logs will be available in CloudWatch Logs along with default log groups.

**Note -** Looking at eb-engine.log, Elastic Beanstalk freshly sets up the unified cloudwatch agent after running `commands` from .ebextension and `prebuild` hooks for every deplyment, so any files created in those steps are being deleted. So I suggest you use `predeploy` hooks to configure this.

**A sample hook to do this -**

Store the hook file at - `.platform/hooks/predeploy/cwa_custom_logs.sh`
and make sure the file is executable in git.

```
#!/bin/sh

filepath="/etc/amazon/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/custom_logs.json"

# Create the file
cat > $filepath << 'EOL'
{
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
                "collect_list": [
                    {
                        "file_path": "path_to_file/app1.log",
                        "log_group_name": "/app/app.log",
                        "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
EOL

# Change file permissions
chmod 000755 $filepath
chown root:root $filepath

# Restart cloudwatch agent
systemctl restart amazon-cloudwatch-agent.service
```

Comment: Want to emphasize the importance of **"make sure the file is executable in git"**, otherwise this won't work.

Comment: We need the deep understanding of cloudwatch agent & elasticbeanstalk for this simple customization... anyway this helped me a lot

Comment: How do you add the elastic beanstalk environment name dynamically to the log_group_name? e.g. I'm trying to achieve something like this: `"log_group_name": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/{environment_name}/var/log/httpd/access_log"`

Comment: @contool You can get the environment name from [get-config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms-scripts.html). I am using a python script with `subprocess` module to run bash commands and create the json file.

Comment: Thanks for this @gowthz - this put me on the right track, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The log files you mentioned in the question are hard coded into config file `/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/beanstalk.json`:

```
{
        "logs": {
                "logs_collected": {
                        "files": {
                                "collect_list": [
                                        {
                                                "file_path": "/var/log/eb-engine.log",
                                                "log_group_name": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/A03cBeanstalkApplicationMybeanstalka-env/var/log/eb-engine.log",
                                                "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "file_path": "/var/log/eb-hooks.log",
                                                "log_group_name": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/A03cBeanstalkApplicationMybeanstalka-env/var/log/eb-hooks.log",
                                                "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "file_path": "/var/log/nginx/access.log",
                                                "log_group_name": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/A03cBeanstalkApplicationMybeanstalka-env/var/log/nginx/access.log",
                                                "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "file_path": "/var/log/nginx/error.log",
                                                "log_group_name": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/A03cBeanstalkApplicationMybeanstalka-env/var/log/nginx/error.log",
                                                "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "file_path": "/var/log/web.stdout.log",
                                                "log_group_name": "/aws/elasticbeanstalk/A03cBeanstalkApplicationMybeanstalka-env/var/log/web.stdout.log",
                                                "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

The [aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-cloudwatchlogs) does not have any option to add extra log files.

It seems to me that you would have to  customize the config files through `extensions` config files.